# JoomShaper Carousel module wont work

Tags: joomla-extensions

I recently downloaded and installed successfully the JoomShaper Carousel module. However when I tried to create a module it displayed:

> Warning:
>       JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\FairywaveDS\images

(where Fairywave is my sites name not FairywaveDS) and also

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fairywave\libraries\joomla\filesystem\folder.php on line 688.

As a result, I am unable to access the carousel source.

I tried to rename the whole directory, but it added an extra DS. I also tried to look into the php files to see if I could spot the problem, but being still a novice I was unable locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

DS is constant directory separator, it was used in Joomla 2.5 and
this Extension is for that joomla version.

> The DS constant has been removed. If you really need it you can use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead. [Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#General_changes)

To fix this issue you need edit this file

> C:\xampp\htdocs\Fairywave\modules\mod_shaper_carousel\elements\foldertree.php

and add this code (it can be before class declaration)

```
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```